# How elastic is assigning weight to terms in searched query?

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I have gone through  [Theory behind relevance scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#boolean-model)  and have got one question but could not find answer on google

My question is on below section in the link

> Imagine that we have a query for “happy hippopotamus.” A common word
> like happy will have a low weight, while an uncommon term like
> hippopotamus will have a high weight. Let’s assume that happy has a
> weight of 2 and hippopotamus has a weight of 5.

How come elastic has determined the weight for each word in query ? Does elastic has predefined weight of each word in it dictionary

**Update:-**

Look at Figure 28 in the link, I see the four lines . I understand the 3 blue lines corresponding to each document. These blue lines represent
the weight of each word/terms(words in query) against each document. My question is on green line. How it is drawn(weight has been calculated here ) ?

Comment: I got my questioned answered at this http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi4107/cosine_tf_idf_example.pdf. I was looking for this only.

Answer (score 0):

The weight is calculated for each word per document. It is based on term frequency, inverse document frequency, and field-length norm. See [this section of the page you mentioned](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#_putting_it_together).

Comment: That i understood. My question is how to calculate the weight for the words used in query[`happy hippopotamus.”`] not in document ?

Comment: The query isn't weighted. The weights of the words in the document are used to calculate a score for the document based on the query.